# How to replace the getElementById("id").textContent sentence using XPath?

Tags: javascript, dom, xpath

I'm trying to learn XPath and I have a problem. I use to retrieve some text getting the corresponding dom element and asking its value. Eg: if I'm coding a Greasemonkey script and my browser is at: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello_World then, I do:

```
alert(
   document.getElementById("section_0").textContent
);
```

So, I need to do the same with xpath. I have tried:

```
var xpathResult = document.evaluate( "//section_0", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null); 
alert(xpathResult);
```

But I really don't understand why it's not working. I think is the xpathExpression, but I can't find a guide which shows the equivalent to `getElementById`, `getElementsByTagname` or `getElementByClassName` sentences.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalents:

```
getElementById(someid)
//*[@id='someid']

getElementsByTagname(tagname);
//tagname

getElementsByClassName(classname)
//*[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '),' classname ')]
```

Comment: And I replaced with XPathResult.STRING_TYPE

Comment: var xpathResult = document.evaluate( "//*[@id='section_0']", document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE , null); 

console.log(xpathResult.stringValue);

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath should be:

```
//*[@id="section_0"]
```